# Closed form of a set

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space with $W_1, W_2$ subspaces of $V$. Also, we have the set $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ of linearly independent vectors such that: 
$$W_1 = \langle e_1, e_2, e_3 \rangle$$ and $$ W_2 = \langle e_1 + e_2 + e_3,\; 3 e_1 + 2 e_2 + e_1 \rangle.$$

Apparently, $e_1 + e_2 + e_3,\; 3 e_1 + 2 e_2 + e_3$ are linearly independent vectors. Also, it is true that $W_2 \subset W_1$.

Is there a way to write in a closed form the set $W_1 \setminus W_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write $W_2$ as the set
$$
\{ae_1+be_2+ce_3\mid a-b=b-c\}
$$
which means that your set is exactly the negation of this:
$$
W_1\setminus W_2=\{ae_1+be_2+ce_3\mid a-b\neq b-c\}
$$

Comment: Actually, what I had in mind is more general. Assuming $W_2 = \langle a e_1 + b e_2 + c e_3,\; d e_1 + e e_2 + f e_3 \rangle$, with $(a,b,c),\, (d,e,f)$  linearly independent vectors,  how would I deal with it?

Comment: @thanasissdr Since $W_2$ is a linear subspace of $W_3$ with _codimension one_ (that means the dimension is one less), there will always be _one_ defining (linear) equation (without constant terms) like the one in my answer. In this case it was $a-b=b-c$ (or some equivalent statement like $2a-2b=a-c$ or $c-b=b-a$). Generally it takes some work to find the equation, but it is _always_ there. Then you do the same as I did in this answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the info.